# Showing Tool-tips while Application is in the System Tray?

Tags: vb.net, tooltip, system-tray

In my application when it is iconized in the system tray, and through a `ContextMenuStrip1` displays a context menu and when I click the icon I can choose what to display; the application, close it etc.

Now, when the mouse is over the icon I would like to show a tooltip (property that unfortunately does not have, but that have the individual menu items), it always shows me the name of the menu object: `ContextMenuStrip1`, even in its text property set something else.

Since at some times the app makes updates in background I would like to show under the icon a small progressbar as do some application. How is this possible in vb.net? (I'm using VB2012)

Comment: Does your context menu have a mouseover event?  with screen coordinates?

Comment: Might be better if you where to split this question up into separate issues.  Not sure if your problem is tooltips, the menu items or showing a progress bar.  Some working examples might also help

Comment: tgolisch: I think so you.

Comment: To Hursey: I'm sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself. For me, the issues presented would be of the same type and context. I'm going to try to make it clear.

Comment: I inserted the tools into startup form: Notifyicon1 and ContextMenuStrip1
Then i set:
           1 - The ContextMenuStrip property of NotifyIcon1 to ContextMenuStrip1
           2- the text's ownership of ContextMenuStrip1 to a certain value that can 
               be changed by code.
I thought that when the mouse is on the icon in the System Tray the value of the Text property of ContestMenuStrip1 is shown, instead it shows me the Name property.
Now I'd like to know, first of all if it's possible, how you can, by code, show a certain value when the mouse is on the icon

Comment: .For example, when the mouse is on the icon of devices connected via usb I am shown the inscription: 'Safe hardware removal...'.So I wish I could do something like that.                                                                                                               Thank you for your attention and for any useful code example

Comment: You should add that detail to your question, rather than in a comment.

Comment: You can show "progress" by swapping in a series of new icons.

Comment: Just checking; have you already added a ToolTip control to the main form? This is what gives you the `.tooltip` property of all objects on that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.
I resolved you need to use the Text property of the notifyIcon object.